# Ordinal classification with xgboost

Tags: xgboost

I am working in the problem where the dependent variables are ordered classes, such as `bad`, `good`, `very good`.

How could I declare this problem in `xgboost` instead of normal `classification` or `regression`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can run 2 xgboost binary classifiers

- 1 classifier  classifies if sample is (good or very good)
- 2 classifier classfies if sample is very good
- if both true on unseen data classify as very good
- if only 1st one true, second false  classify as good
   both false=> classify as bad

Comment: What to do if first false but second true?

Comment: if both classfiers trained well, should happen only rarely and should be classified as bad. if need more tuning can output probabilities and compare probabilities instead of labels

Comment: Indeed, this is probably a better situation than the regression setup in the other answer in the case of conflicting uncertainty. You could just output "I don't know," or if a decision is required, make sure the classifiers are probabilistic and well-calibrated.

Comment: You can also use the prediction/probabilities of earlier labels as features for the higher labels. For example, the classifier 2 can be given the probability that classifier 1 already indicated it was at least 'good' as a feature

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a regression setup, e.g. bad=0, good=0.5, very good = 1 for labels, and then postprocess output of XGBoost, such as pred_value < 0.25 => prediction_label=bad, pred_value >= 0.25 and pred_value < 0.75 => prediction_label=good and so on.

Comment: +1, but the two-classifier ordinal approach seems more flexible.